# Problem with Numpy Arctan function applied to array

Tags: python

I've just started a project that requires comparing the relative brightness of four images. I've got this running in MATLAB, but I'd like the program to be usable in Python too. Compared to MATLAB, the array `dimQU` seems to be correct.

However, taking `arctan` of the array just returns 0s. Is there a proper way to apply `arctan` element wise across a `numpy` array?

Thanks for any help!

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
im0 = io.imread("0_deg.bmp", as_grey=True)
im225 = io.imread("111.34_deg.bmp", as_grey=True)
im45 = io.imread("133.84_deg.bmp", as_grey=True)
im675 = io.imread("156.34_deg.bmp", as_grey=True)


dimQ = np.subtract(im0, im45)
dimU = np.subtract(im225, im675)
dimQU = np.divide(dimQ,dimU)

dimP = 1/2*np.arctan2(dimQ,dimU)
dimP2 = 1/2*np.arctan(dimQU)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types for your matrices is integers, so you are not properly creating `dimQU`.

After your `imread`, use `np.asarray(xx, dtype=np.float)` to get floating point numbers and the arctan you want.

Same for `1/2`, use `.5` directly.